# java: text file encoding support utf8 and ansi

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

first i like to explain our usecase.
Users can upload some text files using our website. The file will be stored in a folder and will be read using java.

Our problem: Most users using ansi encoded text files but some uses utf-8 encoding.

If i read the text file in java i did not read the file correctly. For example the Word "Äpfel" will be read as "?pfel".

I know i can use the encoding settings in my reader:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvFile), "UTF-8"));
```

But how can i determine the correct coding?

My idea is to read the file once and check if there is any unknown char like "?pfel" but how can i check the char is not correct?

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( fi ));
while ( in.ready() ) {
        String row = in.readLine();
        ...
        How can i check row contains unkown chars ??????
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your general approach is good: process the file first to detect the encoding. I would generally check if it is a valid UTF-8. If it contains byte sequences illegal in UTF-8, it is likely ANSI. You can go to great length here and even implement statistical analysis.  But the result will not be perfect in all cases. So you might consider additionally presenting a preview and having the user confirm or override it.

Comment: The ICU4J library contains a [CharsetDector](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CharsetDetector.html) class for this purpose.